# Send message from telegram via API

Tags: telegram-bot

I am able to send messages from python to Telegram, but I cant seem to find the reverse.
I need to get the message from telegram channel and send it to a certain server using Api. Server can consume that Api and that's not my question. I need to know if Telegram can generate that post request.

Answer (score 0):

Your bot should be a member or administrator of that channel. And then your bot will receive an [update](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/#update) containing `channel_post`.

**Note**: You can't join your bot to channels or groups unless you're the owner or administrator of the channel. (Bots themselves do not have the ability to join, you add them manually)